# jQuery removeAttr('type') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is very simple

```
$('#button').removeAttr('type');
```

triggers an error on firebug

```
type property can't be changed
```

I have 2 questions:

- How to get around this?
- Is there a reference with a list of properties that can't be changed?

Thanks

**EDIT**

What I want to do is:

Prevent the button from submitting the form.

Note: my button is included as a html template, the form code is not accessible form me.
Something like:

```
include 'form.php';
include 'buttons.php';
```

where I have control only on **buttons.php**

Comment: you have the answer `type property can't be changed`

Comment: half an answer, still the list :)

Comment: Since you can't change the type of an element, you will have to replace it with a new element.

Comment: Good idea to ask about your actual problem from the start. See *[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't change an `input`'s `type` in IE (<9?) after it has been inserted into the DOM. jQuery raises an error for all browsers because of this.

From source:

```
    set: function( elem, value ) {
            // We can't allow the type property to be changed (since it causes problems in IE)
            if ( rtype.test( elem.nodeName ) && elem.parentNode ) {
                jQuery.error( "type property can't be changed" );
```

**There are no other cases** I know about (or jQuery knows about) and how to get around this depends a lot on what you are trying to do in the first place. Consider creating a new element with different type and using that for example.

Edit: To prevent the button from submitting a form, you can use:

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or (credit Tim Down):

```
$("#button").prop("disabled", true);
```

---

To prevent form from being submitted through any means, you can use:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Setting the button to be disabled would seem to be a better option. It's simpler and provides feedback to the user. `$("#button")[0].disabled = true;`

Comment: @TimDown indeed and makes the button unavailable through tabbing etc. :) thanks for the idea

Comment: Disabling the button is not possible, because other function will be bound to it

Comment: Doesn't returning false also prevent the form from being submitted? Both in form submit and button click. Is `e.preventDefault()` better in some way?

Comment: @Svish when you `return false` from jQuery event handler, it will call `e.preventDefault()` as well as `e.stopPropagation()`. From jQuery source: `if ( ret === false ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
      }`

Answer (score 6):

you can replace it:

```
$('#button').replaceWith('<input type="text" value="text"/>');
```

or use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Great suggestion - and a nice alternative to simply changing the `type` - and (though this may or may not be a benefit) - this will also remove any other button handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to disable the submit button:

If you are using jQuery < 1.6
do this:

```
$("#button").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.6+:

```
$("#button").prop("disabled", true);
```

See this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)  for references why.