# Is there a list of protected html properties?

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery removeAttr('type') doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031966/jquery-removeattrtype-doesnt-work)

When I try

```
$('#button').removeAttr('type');
```

I get an error:

```
type property cannot be changed
```

I was wondering if there is an accurate list of *protected* html properties.

Comment: why do you post your question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031966/jquery-removeattrtype-doesnt-work

Comment: IE cannot changes the type attribute

Comment: in the other question, answered how to get around, now I'm asking if there is othe protected properties

Comment: @skafandri read my answer more carefully, there aren't. I say that in my answer.

Comment: in the other question I read "Is there a reference with a list of properties that can't be changed?"

Comment: yes, people didn't seen it, answered only the first part...

Comment: @Esailija, your answer seems to contain the source "I know about it", but not the proof in jquery website or somewhere else. This is what probably raises this question again, because you were the only one who even tried answering that part.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius why would there be "proof in jQuery website"? Just read the jQuery source code. There you can see how many properties it protects.

Comment: Well I was trying to explain my impression of your answer :) Sorry if I made you mad about that :)